# how to separate a list of names in a text file separated by a space

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Need to breakup text in a file that is separated by spaces.

Example

```
Smith,John  Jones,Sarah  Tucker,Sam  Tucker,Sarah
```

How do I break this up to look like this:

```
Smith,John
Jones,Sarah
Tucker,Sam
Tucker,Sarah
```

I've tried `awk -F' ' { print $0 } filename`   but this doesnt read the space in between.  thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can iterate over each fields separated by space and print them:

```
$ cat file
Smith,John  Jones,Sarah  Tucker,Sam  Tucker,Sarah
```

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
Smith,John
Jones,Sarah
Tucker,Sam
Tucker,Sarah
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' 'NF' file
Smith,John
Jones,Sarah
Tucker,Sam
Tucker,Sarah
```

or

```
$ awk -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
Smith,John
Jones,Sarah
Tucker,Sam
Tucker,Sarah
```

Answer (score 2):

If the fields are tab separated,

```
tr '\t' '\n' < file
```

If they are separated by one or more spaces,

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < file
```

Not all `tr` implementations support these C-style backslash escapes. Consult your local manual page for alternatives (or just pass the separators literally -- in many shells, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> tab yields a literal tab, and a newline can legitimately go between two single quotes without any escaping).